# Implementing toolbar for webpage

Tags: html, facebook, twitter, toolbar, translate

I saw the html toolbar having functions for translate, facebook, like, twitter, etc. How do I implement it, I tried to view source by downloading the code or view source online, it confuses me. Can anyone provide a simple explanation which I can built on?

Ref: 
http://www.motherandchildhealth.com/Breastfeeding/JackNewman/newman_gentian.html

Comment: What exactly confuses you? Perhaps you could have a look here: http://www.meebo.com/websites/

Comment: I'm not sure how I got points minus for asking simple questions for the very fact that I am not a web programmer. Such petty response is very disappointing. 

I am also glad to have very helpful and warm people.
Thank you, Luzhin and MikeD, for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML code you refer to shows that all toolbar related stuff happens in a cascade of `<div>` all named ***...wibiya...***. Googeling this we end up at http://www.wibiya.com/ which has all the info.

Doing a bit more reading of the `<header>` of reference we see wibiya is based on jQuery and needs a library .... should be easy to implement